# Java Read Large Text File With 70million line of text

Tags: java, io

I have a big test file with 70 million lines of text.
I have to read the file line by line.

I used two different approaches:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FilePath),"unicode");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while((cur=br.readLine()) != null);
```

and

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File(FilePath), "unicode");
while(it.hasNext()) cur=it.nextLine();
```

Is there another approach that can make this task faster?

Comment: What are you doing with these lines? A multithreaded solution can speed things up if it can be applied (and that depends on what you are doing with your data and how it is stored on disk)

Comment: "Faster" how?  Less CPU time?  Less wall time?  Something else?  My guess is that your wall time for just a straight read will be dominated by the actual disk I/O.  But depending on what you're trying to do, separating CPU-heavy and I/O-heavy tasks to different threads may give you a significant performance boost.

Comment: better to use java 8 streaming feature

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1) I am sure there is no difference speedwise, both use FileInputStream internally and buffering

2) You can take measurements and see for yourself

3) Though there's no performance benefits I like the 1.7 approach

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    for (String line = null; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        //
    }
}
```

4) Scanner based version

```
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
        }
        // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
        if (sc.ioException() != null) {
            throw sc.ioException();
        }
    }
```

5) This may be faster than the rest

```
try (SeekableByteChannel ch = Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1000);
    for(;;) {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        int n = ch.read(bb);
        // add chars to line
        // ...
    }
}
```

it requires a bit of coding but it can be really faster because of `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`. It allows OS to read bytes from file to `ByteBuffer` directly, without copying

6) Parallel processing would definitely increase speed. Make a big byte buffer, run several tasks that read bytes from file into that buffer in parallel, when ready find first end of line, make a `String`, find next...

Comment: +1 Most of the time spent is a) reading the data from disk or b) if it's in disk cache it will be copying, converting and aligning the bytes into lines. The only way to make it faster is to avoid using a text format or creating an index if you want to load lines at random.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev does it work for file size is greather than 1 GB?

Comment: All 3 ways should be good for any file size since they read data by chunks instead of loading all data in memory

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev I have a similar use case but I have to process each line exactly once. For maintaining this idempotent behavior using a distributed DB seems like a overkill and cost ineffective as well. Can you suggest something else as I have to process it parallelly to finish it quickly

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking out at performance, you could have a look at the `java.nio.*` packages - those are supposedly faster than `java.io.*`

Comment: They are faster for binary, but for text they can be more cumbersome than useful.

Answer (score 9):

In Java 8, for anyone looking now to read file large files line by line,

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\myfile.txt"));
lines.forEach(l -> {
  // Do anything line by line   
});
```

Answer (score 8):

[image]I actually did a research in this topic for months in my free time and came up with a benchmark and here is a code to benchmark all the different ways to read a File line by line.The individual performance may vary based on the underlying system.
I ran on a windows 10 Java 8 Intel i5 HP laptop:Here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadComplexDelimitedFile {
    private static long total = 0;
    private static final Pattern FIELD_DELIMITER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\^\\|\\^");

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void readFileUsingScanner() {

        String s;
        try (Scanner stdin = new Scanner(new File(this.getClass().getResource("input.txt").getPath()))) {
            while (stdin.hasNextLine()) {
                s = stdin.nextLine();
                String[] fields = FIELD_DELIMITER_PATTERN.split(s, 0);
                total = total + fields.length;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }

    }

    //Winner
    private void readFileUsingCustomBufferedReader() {

        try (CustomBufferedReader stdin = new CustomBufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(this.getClass().getResource("input.txt").getPath())))) {
            String s;
            while ((s = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = FIELD_DELIMITER_PATTERN.split(s, 0);
                total += fields.length;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }

    }


    private void readFileUsingBufferedReader() {

        try (BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(this.getClass().getResource("input.txt").getPath())))) {
            String s;
            while ((s = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = FIELD_DELIMITER_PATTERN.split(s, 0);
                total += fields.length;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

    private void readFileUsingLineReader() {

        try (LineNumberReader stdin = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(this.getClass().getResource("input.txt").getPath())))) {
            String s;
            while ((s = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = FIELD_DELIMITER_PATTERN.split(s, 0);
                total += fields.length;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

    private void readFileUsingStreams() {

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines((new File(this.getClass().getResource("input.txt").getPath())).toPath())) {
            total += stream.mapToInt(s -> FIELD_DELIMITER_PATTERN.split(s, 0).length).sum();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void readFileUsingBufferedReaderFileChannel() {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("input.txt").getPath())) {
            try (FileChannel inputChannel = fis.getChannel()) {
                try (CustomBufferedReader stdin = new CustomBufferedReader(Channels.newReader(inputChannel, "UTF-8"))) {
                    String s;
                    while ((s = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] fields = FIELD_DELIMITER_PATTERN.split(s, 0);
                        total = total + fields.length;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //JVM wamrup
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            total += i;
        }
        // We know scanner is slow-Still warming up
        ReadComplexDelimitedFile readComplexDelimitedFile = new ReadComplexDelimitedFile();
        List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<>(50);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            total = 0;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            //readComplexDelimitedFile.readFileUsingScanner();
            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            long timeDifference = stopTime - startTime;
            longList.add(timeDifference);

        }
        System.out.println("Time taken for readFileUsingScanner");
        longList.forEach(System.out::println);
        // Actual performance test starts here

        longList = new ArrayList<>(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total = 0;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            readComplexDelimitedFile.readFileUsingBufferedReaderFileChannel();
            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            long timeDifference = stopTime - startTime;
            longList.add(timeDifference);

        }
        System.out.println("Time taken for readFileUsingBufferedReaderFileChannel");
        longList.forEach(System.out::println);
        longList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total = 0;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            readComplexDelimitedFile.readFileUsingBufferedReader();
            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            long timeDifference = stopTime - startTime;
            longList.add(timeDifference);

        }
        System.out.println("Time taken for readFileUsingBufferedReader");
        longList.forEach(System.out::println);
        longList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total = 0;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            readComplexDelimitedFile.readFileUsingStreams();
            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            long timeDifference = stopTime - startTime;
            longList.add(timeDifference);

        }
        System.out.println("Time taken for readFileUsingStreams");
        longList.forEach(System.out::println);
        longList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total = 0;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            readComplexDelimitedFile.readFileUsingCustomBufferedReader();
            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            long timeDifference = stopTime - startTime;
            longList.add(timeDifference);

        }
        System.out.println("Time taken for readFileUsingCustomBufferedReader");
        longList.forEach(System.out::println);
        longList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total = 0;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            readComplexDelimitedFile.readFileUsingLineReader();
            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            long timeDifference = stopTime - startTime;
            longList.add(timeDifference);

        }
        System.out.println("Time taken for readFileUsingLineReader");
        longList.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

I had to rewrite BufferedReader to avoid synchronized and a couple of boundary conditions that is not needed.(Atleast that's what I felt.It is not unit tested so use it at your own risk.)

```
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

/**
 * Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to
 * provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.
 * <p>
 * <p> The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used.  The
 * default is large enough for most purposes.
 * <p>
 * <p> In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding
 * read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream.  It is
 * therefore advisable to wrap a CustomBufferedReader around any Reader whose read()
 * operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders.  For
 * example,
 * <p>
 * <pre>
 * CustomBufferedReader in
 *   = new CustomBufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
 * </pre>
 * <p>
 * will buffer the input from the specified file.  Without buffering, each
 * invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the
 * file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very
 * inefficient.
 * <p>
 * <p> Programs that use DataInputStreams for textual input can be localized by
 * replacing each DataInputStream with an appropriate CustomBufferedReader.
 *
 * @author Mark Reinhold
 * @see FileReader
 * @see InputStreamReader
 * @see java.nio.file.Files#newBufferedReader
 * @since JDK1.1
 */

public class CustomBufferedReader extends Reader {

    private final Reader in;

    private char cb[];
    private int nChars, nextChar;

    private static final int INVALIDATED = -2;
    private static final int UNMARKED = -1;
    private int markedChar = UNMARKED;
    private int readAheadLimit = 0; /* Valid only when markedChar > 0 */

    /**
     * If the next character is a line feed, skip it
     */
    private boolean skipLF = false;

    /**
     * The skipLF flag when the mark was set
     */
    private boolean markedSkipLF = false;

    private static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192;
    private static int defaultExpectedLineLength = 80;
    private ReadWriteLock rwlock;


    /**
     * Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses an input buffer of
     * the specified size.
     *
     * @param in A Reader
     * @param sz Input-buffer size
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If {@code sz <= 0}
     */
    public CustomBufferedReader(@NotNull final Reader in, int sz) {
        super(in);
        if (sz <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
        this.in = in;
        cb = new char[sz];
        nextChar = nChars = 0;
        rwlock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses a default-sized
     * input buffer.
     *
     * @param in A Reader
     */
    public CustomBufferedReader(@NotNull final Reader in) {
        this(in, defaultCharBufferSize);
    }


    /**
     * Fills the input buffer, taking the mark into account if it is valid.
     */
    private void fill() throws IOException {
        int dst;
        if (markedChar <= UNMARKED) {
            /* No mark */
            dst = 0;
        } else {
            /* Marked */
            int delta = nextChar - markedChar;
            if (delta >= readAheadLimit) {
                /* Gone past read-ahead limit: Invalidate mark */
                markedChar = INVALIDATED;
                readAheadLimit = 0;
                dst = 0;
            } else {
                if (readAheadLimit <= cb.length) {
                    /* Shuffle in the current buffer */
                    System.arraycopy(cb, markedChar, cb, 0, delta);
                    markedChar = 0;
                    dst = delta;
                } else {
                    /* Reallocate buffer to accommodate read-ahead limit */
                    char ncb[] = new char[readAheadLimit];
                    System.arraycopy(cb, markedChar, ncb, 0, delta);
                    cb = ncb;
                    markedChar = 0;
                    dst = delta;
                }
                nextChar = nChars = delta;
            }
        }

        int n;
        do {
            n = in.read(cb, dst, cb.length - dst);
        } while (n == 0);
        if (n > 0) {
            nChars = dst + n;
            nextChar = dst;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads a single character.
     *
     * @return The character read, as an integer in the range
     * 0 to 65535 (<tt>0x00-0xffff</tt>), or -1 if the
     * end of the stream has been reached
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     */
    public char readChar() throws IOException {
        for (; ; ) {
            if (nextChar >= nChars) {
                fill();
                if (nextChar >= nChars)
                    return (char) -1;
            }
            return cb[nextChar++];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads characters into a portion of an array, reading from the underlying
     * stream if necessary.
     */
    private int read1(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (nextChar >= nChars) {
            /* If the requested length is at least as large as the buffer, and
               if there is no mark/reset activity, and if line feeds are not
               being skipped, do not bother to copy the characters into the
               local buffer.  In this way buffered streams will cascade
               harmlessly. */
            if (len >= cb.length && markedChar <= UNMARKED && !skipLF) {
                return in.read(cbuf, off, len);
            }
            fill();
        }
        if (nextChar >= nChars) return -1;
        int n = Math.min(len, nChars - nextChar);
        System.arraycopy(cb, nextChar, cbuf, off, n);
        nextChar += n;
        return n;
    }

    /**
     * Reads characters into a portion of an array.
     * <p>
     * <p> This method implements the general contract of the corresponding
     * <code>{@link Reader#read(char[], int, int) read}</code> method of the
     * <code>{@link Reader}</code> class.  As an additional convenience, it
     * attempts to read as many characters as possible by repeatedly invoking
     * the <code>read</code> method of the underlying stream.  This iterated
     * <code>read</code> continues until one of the following conditions becomes
     * true: <ul>
     * <p>
     * <li> The specified number of characters have been read,
     * <p>
     * <li> The <code>read</code> method of the underlying stream returns
     * <code>-1</code>, indicating end-of-file, or
     * <p>
     * <li> The <code>ready</code> method of the underlying stream
     * returns <code>false</code>, indicating that further input requests
     * would block.
     * <p>
     * </ul> If the first <code>read</code> on the underlying stream returns
     * <code>-1</code> to indicate end-of-file then this method returns
     * <code>-1</code>.  Otherwise this method returns the number of characters
     * actually read.
     * <p>
     * <p> Subclasses of this class are encouraged, but not required, to
     * attempt to read as many characters as possible in the same fashion.
     * <p>
     * <p> Ordinarily this method takes characters from this stream's character
     * buffer, filling it from the underlying stream as necessary.  If,
     * however, the buffer is empty, the mark is not valid, and the requested
     * length is at least as large as the buffer, then this method will read
     * characters directly from the underlying stream into the given array.
     * Thus redundant <code>CustomBufferedReader</code>s will not copy data
     * unnecessarily.
     *
     * @param cbuf Destination buffer
     * @param off  Offset at which to start storing characters
     * @param len  Maximum number of characters to read
     * @return The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the
     * stream has been reached
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     */
    public int read(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int n = read1(cbuf, off, len);
        if (n <= 0) return n;
        while ((n < len) && in.ready()) {
            int n1 = read1(cbuf, off + n, len - n);
            if (n1 <= 0) break;
            n += n1;
        }
        return n;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a line of text.  A line is considered to be terminated by any one
     * of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
     * followed immediately by a linefeed.
     *
     * @param ignoreLF If true, the next '\n' will be skipped
     * @return A String containing the contents of the line, not including
     * any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
     * stream has been reached
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     * @see java.io.LineNumberReader#readLine()
     */
    String readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder s = null;
        int startChar;



        bufferLoop:
        for (; ; ) {

            if (nextChar >= nChars)
                fill();
            if (nextChar >= nChars) { /* EOF */
                if (s != null && s.length() > 0)
                    return s.toString();
                else
                    return null;
            }
            boolean eol = false;
            char c = 0;
            int i;

            /* Skip a leftover '\n', if necessary */



            charLoop:
            for (i = nextChar; i < nChars; i++) {
                c = cb[i];
                if ((c == '\n')) {
                    eol = true;
                    break charLoop;
                }
            }

            startChar = nextChar;
            nextChar = i;

            if (eol) {
                String str;
                if (s == null) {
                    str = new String(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                } else {
                    s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                    str = s.toString();
                }
                nextChar++;
                return str;
            }

            if (s == null)
                s = new StringBuilder(defaultExpectedLineLength);
            s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads a line of text.  A line is considered to be terminated by any one
     * of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
     * followed immediately by a linefeed.
     *
     * @return A String containing the contents of the line, not including
     * any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
     * stream has been reached
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     * @see java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines
     */
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        return readLine(false);
    }

    /**
     * Skips characters.
     *
     * @param n The number of characters to skip
     * @return The number of characters actually skipped
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If <code>n</code> is negative.
     * @throws IOException              If an I/O error occurs
     */
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        if (n < 0L) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("skip value is negative");
        }
        rwlock.readLock().lock();
            long r = n;
            try{
            while (r > 0) {
                if (nextChar >= nChars)
                    fill();
                if (nextChar >= nChars) /* EOF */
                    break;
                if (skipLF) {
                    skipLF = false;
                    if (cb[nextChar] == '\n') {
                        nextChar++;
                    }
                }
                long d = nChars - nextChar;
                if (r <= d) {
                    nextChar += r;
                    r = 0;
                    break;
                } else {
                    r -= d;
                    nextChar = nChars;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            rwlock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return n - r;
    }

    /**
     * Tells whether this stream is ready to be read.  A buffered character
     * stream is ready if the buffer is not empty, or if the underlying
     * character stream is ready.
     *
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     */
    public boolean ready() throws IOException {
        rwlock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            /*
             * If newline needs to be skipped and the next char to be read
             * is a newline character, then just skip it right away.
             */
            if (skipLF) {
                /* Note that in.ready() will return true if and only if the next
                 * read on the stream will not block.
                 */
                if (nextChar >= nChars && in.ready()) {
                    fill();
                }
                if (nextChar < nChars) {
                    if (cb[nextChar] == '\n')
                        nextChar++;
                    skipLF = false;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            rwlock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return (nextChar < nChars) || in.ready();

    }

    /**
     * Tells whether this stream supports the mark() operation, which it does.
     */
    public boolean markSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Marks the present position in the stream.  Subsequent calls to reset()
     * will attempt to reposition the stream to this point.
     *
     * @param readAheadLimit Limit on the number of characters that may be
     *                       read while still preserving the mark. An attempt
     *                       to reset the stream after reading characters
     *                       up to this limit or beyond may fail.
     *                       A limit value larger than the size of the input
     *                       buffer will cause a new buffer to be allocated
     *                       whose size is no smaller than limit.
     *                       Therefore large values should be used with care.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If {@code readAheadLimit < 0}
     * @throws IOException              If an I/O error occurs
     */
    public void mark(int readAheadLimit) throws IOException {
        if (readAheadLimit < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Read-ahead limit < 0");
        }
        rwlock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            this.readAheadLimit = readAheadLimit;
            markedChar = nextChar;
            markedSkipLF = skipLF;
        } finally {
            rwlock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the stream to the most recent mark.
     *
     * @throws IOException If the stream has never been marked,
     *                     or if the mark has been invalidated
     */
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        rwlock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            if (markedChar < 0)
                throw new IOException((markedChar == INVALIDATED)
                        ? "Mark invalid"
                        : "Stream not marked");
            nextChar = markedChar;
            skipLF = markedSkipLF;
        } finally {
            rwlock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        rwlock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            in.close();
        } finally {
            cb = null;
            rwlock.readLock().unlock();
        }

    }

    public Stream<String> lines() {
        Iterator<String> iter = new Iterator<String>() {
            String nextLine = null;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (nextLine != null) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    try {
                        nextLine = readLine();
                        return (nextLine != null);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String next() {
                if (nextLine != null || hasNext()) {
                    String line = nextLine;
                    nextLine = null;
                    return line;
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
            }
        };
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                iter, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL), false);
    }
}
```

And now the results:

Time taken for readFileUsingBufferedReaderFileChannel
2902690903
1845190694
1894071377
1815161868
1861056735
1867693540
1857521371
1794176251
1768008762
1853089582

Time taken for readFileUsingBufferedReader
2022837353
1925901163
1802266711
1842689572
1899984555
1843101306
1998642345
1821242301
1820168806
1830375108

Time taken for readFileUsingStreams
1992855461
1930827034
1850876033
1843402533
1800378283
1863581324
1810857226
1798497108
1809531144
1796345853

Time taken for readFileUsingCustomBufferedReader
1759732702
1765987214
1776997357
1772999486
1768559162
1755248431
1744434555
1750349867
1740582606
1751390934

Time taken for readFileUsingLineReader
1845307174
1830950256
1829847321
1828125293
1827936280
1836947487
1832186310
1820276327
1830157935
1829171481

Process finished with exit code 0

Inference:
The test was run on a 200 MB file.
The test was repeated several times.
The data looked like this

```
Start Date^|^Start Time^|^End Date^|^End Time^|^Event Title ^|^All Day Event^|^No End Time^|^Event Description^|^Contact ^|^Contact Email^|^Contact Phone^|^Location^|^Category^|^Mandatory^|^Registration^|^Maximum^|^Last Date To Register
9/5/2011^|^3:00:00 PM^|^9/5/2011^|^^|^Social Studies Dept. Meeting^|^N^|^Y^|^Department meeting^|^Chris Gallagher^|^cgallagher@schoolwires.com^|^814-555-5179^|^High School^|^2^|^N^|^N^|^25^|^9/2/2011
```

Bottomline not much difference between BufferedReader and my CustomReader and it is very miniscule and hence you can use this to read your file.

Trust me you don't have to break your head.use BufferedReader with readLine,it is properly tested.At worst if you feel you can improve it just override and change it to StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer just to shave off half a second

Comment: I feel like this was a thorough answer about which is faster since it presented hard measurements between all of these methods.  But you had to really read the code to even begin to understand the findings.  Just a little more presentation and this would've made the results easier to understand.  But basically it's about a 5% improvement in writing non-synchronized BufferedReader.  What I found is I can get a 40% improvement just increasing the buffer size from 8K to 64k using default LineNumberReader/BufferedReader.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, but I only needed the bytes from the file.  I read through links provided in the various answers, and ultimately tried writing one similar to #5 in Evgeniy's answer.  They weren't kidding, it took a lot of code.

The basic premise is that each line of text is of unknown length.  I will start with a SeekableByteChannel, read data into a ByteBuffer, then loop over it looking for EOL.  When something is a "carryover" between loops, it increments a counter and then ultimately moves the SeekableByteChannel position around and reads the entire buffer.

It is verbose ... but it works.  It was plenty fast for what I needed, but I'm sure there are more improvements that can be made.

The **process** method is stripped down to the basics for kicking off reading the file.

```
private long startOffset;
private long endOffset;
private SeekableByteChannel sbc;

private final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);

public void process() throws IOException
{
    startOffset = 0;
    sbc = Files.newByteChannel(FILE, EnumSet.of(READ));
    byte[] message = null;
    while((message = readRecord()) != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public byte[] readRecord() throws IOException
{
    endOffset = startOffset;

    boolean eol = false;
    boolean carryOver = false;
    byte[] record = null;

    while(!eol)
    {
        byte data;
        buffer.clear();
        final int bytesRead = sbc.read(buffer);

        if(bytesRead == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        buffer.flip();

        for(int i = 0; i < bytesRead && !eol; i++)
        {
            data = buffer.get();
            if(data == '\r' || data == '\n')
            {
                eol = true;
                endOffset += i;

                if(carryOver)
                {
                    final int messageSize = (int)(endOffset - startOffset);
                    sbc.position(startOffset);

                    final ByteBuffer tempBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(messageSize);
                    sbc.read(tempBuffer);
                    tempBuffer.flip();

                    record = new byte[messageSize];
                    tempBuffer.get(record);
                }
                else
                {
                    record = new byte[i];

                    // Need to move the buffer position back since the get moved it forward
                    buffer.position(0);
                    buffer.get(record, 0, i);
                }

                // Skip past the newline characters
                if(isWindowsOS())
                {
                    startOffset = (endOffset + 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    startOffset = (endOffset + 1);
                }

                // Move the file position back
                sbc.position(startOffset);
            }
        }

        if(!eol && sbc.position() == sbc.size())
        {
            // We have hit the end of the file, just take all the bytes
            record = new byte[bytesRead];
            eol = true;
            buffer.position(0);
            buffer.get(record, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        else if(!eol)
        {
            // The EOL marker wasn't found, continue the loop
            carryOver = true;
            endOffset += bytesRead;
        }
    }

    // System.out.println(new String(record));
    return record;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) is a great way to start.

Also, you need to create test cases in which you read first 10k(or something else, but shouldn't be too small) lines and calculate the reading times accordingly.

Threading might be a good way to go, but it's important that we know what you will be doing with the data.

Another thing to be considered is, how you will store that size of data.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following three methods, my file size is 1M, and I got results:

[image]

I run the program several times it looks that BufferedReader is faster.

```
@Test
public void testLargeFileIO_Scanner() throws Exception {

    long start = new Date().getTime();

    String fileName = "/Downloads/SampleTextFile_1000kb.txt"; //this path is on my local
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    long end = new Date().getTime();

    long time = end - start;
    System.out.println("Scanner Time Consumed => " + time);

}


@Test
 public void testLargeFileIO_BufferedReader() throws Exception {

    long start = new Date().getTime();

    String fileName = "/Downloads/SampleTextFile_1000kb.txt"; //this path is on my local
    try (BufferedReader fileBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        String fileLineContent;
        while ((fileLineContent = fileBufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(fileLineContent);
        }
    }
    long end = new Date().getTime();

    long time = (long) (end - start);
    System.out.println("BufferedReader Time Consumed => " + time);

}


@Test
public void testLargeFileIO_Stream() throws Exception {

    long start = new Date().getTime();

    String fileName = "/Downloads/SampleTextFile_1000kb.txt"; //this path is on my local
    try (Stream inputStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        //inputStream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    long end = new Date().getTime();

    long time = end - start;
    System.out.println("Stream Time Consumed => " + time);

}
```