# Sort by date and time

Tags: java, date, csv

First of all many thanks all for your prompt response. You are all Awesome !!!

Let me eloborate a bit more.

I have CSV which is 2 GB in size. Has 4 Columns: Network_id, uptime, dateAndTimeStamp and directory number.

Network ids look like this:   CBUK12345678
uptime:                       550, 800, 600 (in seconds)
dateAndTimeStamp:             0013-09-14 10:00:00 PM

it has 3 months of data based on dateAndTimeStamp. The interval between each dateAndTimeStamp is 15mins. i.e. if 0013-09-14 10:00:00 PM the next would be 0013-09-14 10:15:00 PM

There are missing timestamp values in the data. 
I want to sort the data for 24 hour period (doesnt matter which date, just have to be 24 hour (86400 seconds) ... once I have sorted the data for complete 24 hours (without any missing values in it) filter out those network ids whose up time is 95% of 86400 second in those 24 hours. i.e. add uptime for each 15 mins and see if its 95% of 86400 secs.

I want to select those network ids

Comment: Put this file in some relational DB, will make your task easier, I believe.

Comment: What does the dateAndTimeStamp column refers to?

Comment: Can you pre-process the file outside the java code as part of the overall process?

Comment: You say the CSV has three columns in it but I only see one column.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14037510/842210)). Going by your description you only need to select data, not sort it. So while you go through each line, check if the line meets the requirement. If yes, save data\ref elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if this query is all you need, maybe you don't need to setup a database backend, and the following may be enough:

```
public void processFile(Reader in, Writer out) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(file, charset);
  while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    processLine(in.nextLine(), out);
  }
}

public void processLine(String line, Writer out) {
  // Line is a class with three fields to represent network, uptime and timestamp
  Line line = parseCSV(line);
  // The filter interface is extracted for testing purposes
  if (filter.accept(line)) {
    out.write(/* whatever */);
  }
}
```

This sample uses a streaming approach, ie lines are evaluated and written to `out` as soon as they are read, since you state your input is 2GB. Note that I purposefully left out any filtering and CSV parsing logic.

For CSV you may use an external library, but for a quick and dirty solution the old `String.split(",")` may be enough. It doesn't work if the input contains escape characters and quotes, but it doesn't seem the case from your description.

The filtering logic may simply compare the uptime against a threshold value (or otherwise please better explain what `dateAndTimeStamp` refers to)

Answer (score 0):

I would import the csv file in a Database and query through the database.

There are some other tools you can use. I cannot garantee that they would work with such big file.

- OpenOffice Database or in Excel
- Use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) (Windows Tool)

> Log parser is a powerful, versatile tool that provides universal query
>   access to text-based data such as log files, XML files and CSV files,
>   as well as key data sources on the Windows® operating system such as
>   the Event Log, the Registry, the file system, and Active Directory®.
>   You tell Log Parser what information you need and how you want it
>   processed. The results of your query can be custom-formatted in text
>   based output, or they can be persisted to more specialty targets like
>   SQL, SYSLOG, or a chart.
>
> Most software is designed to accomplish a limited number of specific
>   tasks. Log Parser is different... the number of ways it can be used is
>   limited only by the needs and imagination of the user. The world is
>   your database with Log Parser

- Python module: [QueryCSV](http://pythonhosted.org/querycsv/)

Comment: I am not sure that querying through a database will be much simpler in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for sort by Date and time, insert that to database. 
when you insert data in database you can sort(order by).