# How to process and save big files with serialization?

Tags: java, xml, csv, serialization, bigdata

I would like to read a big file (it cannot fit in heap as an object). I have to read line by line, process each line and then save (append) in a new file.

I finished first step (loading and processing) and I print output on the console. I don't create an object of data.
I think I must do it on the fly, but I don't know libraries which might be helpful.

What is more I would like to add XML or CSV Serialization.
Do you know some libraries which might solve this problem?

```
for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; ) {
     String processedNewLine = processLine(Line);
     //and I would like to serialize to XML (append)
     XMLSerialiazer.serialize(processedNewLine, xmlTemp.getPath());

}
```

Comment: Your question has been answered before, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037404/java-read-large-text-file-with-70million-line-of-text

Comment: @M.RAshouri the question linked by you answer only for a csv file. Is not useful for an XML, because reading it row by row doesn't solve the problem, and sometimes the whole xml is saved in a single row to save space.

Comment: You want to serialize every porocessed line as an XML file? Why?

Comment: Each processed line should be XML part of a one big XML file: `<line><field1>name</field1>...</line>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use .csv files you need simply read them line by line. It is not really necessary to use a special library and you can work also with very big files without problems.

If you use .xml files you need a [SAX parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html). Basically a SAX parser is a parser that operates on events (like open tag, close tag) instead of building the whole structure in memory as it happens with a DOM parser.

Comment: With CSV was easy, but for XML it's more complicated. Finally I treat XML as Random Access File and append new lines to the end. It's not clean, but very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alternate approach to using available XML serialization libraries, please take a look into [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) from google.

[Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial)

[Git source](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/java)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo), one of the fastest serialization libraries.